# Parsing response from a string in python

Tags: python, jms

I am receiving the following response from a JMS queue and I want to be able to parse it to fetch the values of error_code and error_description. I intend to use python to parse this string.

```
    TextMessage={ Header={ JMSMessageID={ID:emsfuat-p.111111111111:2} JMSDestination={Queue[abc.def.ghijk.lmno.pqrs.tuv.wxyz]} JMSReplyTo={null} JMSDeliveryMode={PERSISTENT} JMSRedelivered={false} JMSCorrelationID={ABC201113124721} JMSType={null} JMSTimestamp={Sat Nov 01 17:57:15 GST 2014} JMSExpiration={0} JMSPriority={4} } Properties={ } Text={<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REPLY><header><msg_type>TT</msg_type><msg_function>POSTING</msg_function><src_application>FinBroker</src_application><msg_id>ABC123456789</msg_id><bank_id>EBI</bank_id><timestamp>2014-11-01T17:57:15.19+04:00</timestamp><error_code>ABC-DEF-GHI-000</error_code><error_description>Success</error_description></header></REPLY>} }
```

my question is can you help me identify the format in which this response is sent and how can I parse this format using python?

Comment: So what is your question? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyhjb ... http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/517510-python-jms ...

Comment: sorry, my question is can you help me identify the format in which this response is sent and how can I parse this format using python?

Answer (score 0):

as specified above in your  tag, it seems to be a general xml tags.
if it is, then you can use lxml's etee module for xpath. 
for example:

`def parseXML(path):
        from lxml import etree
        tree = etree.tree(path)
        root = tree.getroot()
        get_error_code = root.xpath('//')`

which will give error code, if you do not have sub nodes, then directly you can access node using 'xpath'

Comment: etree doesn't seem to be able to handle this as this isn't a regular xml format. any clue as to what format this text is in?